# iterate each div attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the rgb and index value of each div. In the console I get everything correctly (index and B
background color for each div). Trying to add each value to a *p* in every *div* I have only the last value repeated for each *div*: the hex of blue and the number 5.
How can I solve?

```
.red {
    background-color:red; 
}.orange {
    background-color:orange; 
}
.yellow {
    background-color:yellow; 
}
.purple {
    background-color:purple; 
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue; 
}
<div class="red"><p></p></div>
<div class="orange"><p></p></div>
<div class="yellow"><p></p></div>
<div class="purple"><p></p></div>
<div class="blue"><p></p></div>

$('div').each(function(index) {
  var x = $(this).css('background-color');
  $("div p").text(index+x);
  console.log(index+x);
});
```

- [Log] rgb(255, 0, 0) #ff0000
- [Log] rgb(255, 165, 0) #ffa500
- [Log] rgb(255, 255, 0) #ffff00
- [Log] rgb(128, 0, 128) #800080
- [Log] rgb(0, 0, 255) #0000ff

Comment: Keep a count for the div you are on?

Comment: in the console I have a correct count (index) for each div and the background color for each one. in html for each <p> only the last value index and color (blue)

Comment: Sorry @KevinB, but I disagree with your duplicate selection. The duplicate shows the selection of existing elements when they wanted a new one. This is not the same thing.  (I'm not saying there aren't duplicates that could be selected, but that isn't one of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following...

```
$("div p").text(index+x);
```

To...

```
$(this).find("p").text(index+x);
```

As currently you are finding ALL `<div>` elements again, and populating the `<p>` in each one... that is why you're seeing the final value across all

```js
$('div').each(function(index) {
  var x = $(this).css('background-color');
  $(this).find("p").text(index+x);
  console.log(index+x);
});
```

```css
.red {
    background-color:red; 
}.orange {
    background-color:orange; 
}
.yellow {
    background-color:yellow; 
}
.purple {
    background-color:purple; 
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="red"><p></p></div>
<div class="orange"><p></p></div>
<div class="yellow"><p></p></div>
<div class="purple"><p></p></div>
<div class="blue"><p></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you had the right function, but need to use .eq(index) to actually effect that specific index within the foreach function. This is similar to accessing indexes in arrays, such as randomArray(0) => 1.

```js
$('div').each(function(index) {
  var x = $(this).css('background-color');
  $("div p").eq(index).text(index+x);
  console.log(index+x);
});
```

```css
.red {
    background-color:red; 
}

.cyan {
  background-color:cyan;
}

.green {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red"><p></p></div>
<div class="cyan"><p></p></div>
<div class="green"><p></p></div>
```

Comment: Although your code works, having `$("div p").eq(index)` within the loop is relatively "expensive" as you're having to find all the items each each loop to then only select the indexed one

Comment: Well that's something new I learned today. Didn't know that eq(index) calls everything up to it. Thanks

Comment: @KevinB - ok, I'll take your word for it... but I can't see from the code you've linked to how the `.eq` function doesn't first require a full list of all elements found in `$("div p")`.  Happy to remove my comment if you fully believe it to be false

Comment: @freefaller You're correct, i was just focusing on the .eq method, ignoring the fact that they first had to select it (hence the deletion)

Comment: Thanks @KevinB (I thought I was going mad). Of course another option would be to use the `:eq` selector, which is maybe what you were thinking of?

Comment: No, i just flat out ignored the selector portion of it, i thought you were saying the .eq method did some kind of looping.

Comment: Definitely makes sense, thanks all!